# jqgrid divide a text box value and affect another text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-php

i using the `jqgrid` . i have to do a simple calculation on EDIT and ADD modal dialog with text boxes  ,  i have to get a value from one text box and i have to divide by 8 then i have to show an another textbox . I can able get the `id` of the textboxes (Not value ) . Then i try to alert the value of that text box ,but its not working ..

i try the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $("#editmodmyFirstGrid").on("change", '#pds', function(event) {

        alert('value is entered');

    });
 });
```

here `#editmodmyFirstGrid` is an id of the edit dialogue box , and `#pds` is assigned to text box id.

Answer (score 0):

If i really understood your question, you need to calculate the second text-box value based on first text-box value. I am not sure what is the role of jQgrid here. You can calculate the second text-box value like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#calculatedValue").val($("#actualValue").val()/8);
});
```

And the respective html part looks like,

```
<input type="text" id="actualValue" value="800" />
<input type="text" id="calculatedValue" />
```

The working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FeT3z/).

Let me know if this helps. Please read the [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before you post any question.